# Copying data of an unknown type into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memcpy, memory-alignment

I've got a function that receives data of an unknown type allocated on the heap that I'd like to copy it into a specific position in an array. The issue is that this function can't have access to the type of the data; just to its address and size.

This is the information the function has access to:

```
unsigned int count; /* length of the array */
unsigned int pos; /* index in the array */
void *data; /* source data */
size_t elemsize; /* sizeof data type */
void *array = malloc(elemcount * elemsize);
```

The solution that I've reached was to use memcpy and cast the array to char* in order to be able to address it on a byte-level.

```
memcpy((char*) array + elemsize * pos, (char*) data, elemsize);
```

However, I've read about possible problems when using memcpy with unaligned pointers in certain architectures.

Would casting the source data to char* make this operation safe?

Are there any situations in which addressing the array by converting it to char* (i.e. any system in which `sizeof(char) != 1`) or using memcpy in this way could cause problems?

Comment: You cannot accidently try to use `memcpy()` on mis-aligned data, because its arguments have the minimum alignment requirement aka `_Alignas(char)`. Only the first cast is neccessary, because pointer-arithmetic on `void*` is a compile error. The second one is superfluous.

Comment: I added the second cast because of some information I read about how [ARM Compilers handle memcpy](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3934.html).

Comment: Code's call to `malloc()` returned a well aligned pointer for `array`.  `array` is properly aligned for _all types_ that have a size of `elemsize`.  `memcpy()` works on pointers as if they were `char *` - no problems here with nice use of `(char*) array + elemsize * pos`.  Looked over the ARM link and see that it recommends `char *` cast.  Do not yet see, per the C spec, why the cast is needed.

Comment: @JoãoPinheiro Interesting link. However, it seems the link here talks about inferring alignment from the pointer type - that is, if you for some reason do something like `int *foo = array` then it will assume 4 byte alignment. It doesn't apply in this case

Comment: @chux `A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different
object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned57) for the
pointed-to type, the behavior is undeﬁned.` (6.3.2.3) :)

Comment: @mnunber How does §6.3.2.3 7 apply to the need or not concerning the `char *` cast to the 2nd arg of `memcpy()`?  Without the cast, it is some pointer type -> `const void *`.  With the cast, it is some pointer type to `char *` to `const void *`.

Comment: @chux @chux - You're correct that the prototype of `memcpy` itself does not care; however by passing an unaligned pointer, or more specifically, _casting an unaligned pointer to a type whose alignment constraints are violated_ already enters the bounds of UB; so technically speaking it's illegal to do anything with such a pointer. The ARM manual just provides some implementation specific allowances (i.e. defines behavior for unaligned pointers with memcpy) for what is normally considered UB according to the standard anyway. Of course none of this is relevant to OP's question though :)

Answer (score 2):

> Would casting the source data to char* make this operation safe?

That makes no difference.

> Are there any situations in which addressing the array by converting it to char* (i.e. any system in which sizeof(char) != 1) or using memcpy in this way could cause problems?

There are no systems with `sizeof(char) != 1`. The standard specifies that it must be `1`.

There is never any problem using `memcpy` so long as the bounds are not exceeded of the objects being read and written, and the destination is writable, and the objects don't overlap. In particular there is not any alignment problem.

(There may be a problem when you attempt to access the object that you copied into, if you didn't successfully build up a valid representation for that object).

> I've read about possible problems when using memcpy with unaligned pointers in certain architectures.

Either you misunderstood what you read, or the information was wrong. If you are talking about the code in the linked ARM article:

```
void example (unsigned int * const unaligned_ptr)
{
```

if `unaligned_ptr` is not correctly aligned for `unsigned int` then the behaviour is already undefined before execution enters the body of the function. The page seems to be offering a way to attempt to recover from undefined behaviour . This is a rather bad idea IMHO, it'd be better to not initiate undefined behaviour in the first place; or to detect it and then throw some sort of fatal exception so that the problem can be debugged and corrected.

Comment: You mean detect it beforehand, because afterwards is much too late.